# PHP Session time out too fast

Tags: php, session

I have a web page `index.php` it is a form that log a user into a session.

```
<?php
//start session
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['User']);
session_destroy();  
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

//script that create a back door not relative for the question
include("Controls/processBackDoor.php");
?>
<html>
<head>
    //CSS, Javascript, meta tag, icon and title here
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divWrapper">
        <div id="divLogin">
            <div id="divAnglais">
                <a href="EN/Index.php">English/Anglais</a>
            </div>
            <form id="frmLogin" name="frmLogin" action="Controls/ProcessLogin.php" method="POST">
                <div id="divTextLogin">
                    <ul id="textLogin" class="frmLogin">
                        <li>Nom d'utilisateur: </li>
                        <li></br></li>
                        <li>Mot de passe: </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="divInputLogin">
                    <ul id="inputLogin" class="frmLogin">
                        <li><input type="text" id="txtUsername" name="txtUsername"/></li>
                        <li></br></li>
                        <li><input type="password" id="txtPassword" name="txtPassword"/></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="divButtonLogin">
                    <input type="submit" id="cmdLogin" class="cmdLogin" onmouseover="className='cmdLoginOver'" onmouseout="className='cmdLogin'" value="Connexion"/></br>
                    <?php
                    if(isset($_SESSION['msg']))
                    {
                        echo "<div class='divLogin'>".$_SESSION['msg']."</div>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So normal form. Here is the code that validate the user:

```
<?php
//resume session
session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
//those are the classes used to connecte to the DB
include("../Models/cConnexion.php");
include("../Models/cConstanteConnexion.php");
include("../Models/cUser.php");

//Connexion
$cn = new cConnexion($ConnexionWebHost, $ConnexionWebDBName, $ConnexionWebLogin, $ConnexionWebPassword);

//reset session variables
$_SESSION['User'] = null;
$_SESSION['Group'] = null;
$_SESSION['Site'] = null;

if($cn->DBConnexion())
{
$user = array('username'=>$_POST['txtUsername'], 'password'=>$_POST['txtPassword']);
$getUser = $cn->SecureSelect("SELECT 
                            us_username, us_password, us_firstName,
                            us_lastName, us_email

FROM user 
                        WHERE BINARY us_username = :username 
                            AND BINARY us_password = :password", $user);

if($getUser <> null)
{

    while($User = $getUser->fetch())
    {

        $_SESSION['User'] = $User;

    }
}

if(isset($_SESSION['User']))
{
    unset($_SESSION['msg']);
    header("Location: ../Pages/Accueil.php");
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Votre username ou votre mot de passe est invalide.";
    header("Location: ../Index.php");
}
}

?>
```

And finally I have this code on every other page to validate if the user was login. if he is not login he must be redirect to `index.php` so he can login.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['User']) || $_SESSION['User'] == null)
{
header("Location: ../Index.php");
}
```

The problem is that every time a change from page to page it redirect me to `index.php`.
I was thinking maybe I unset the session somewhere else in the code but I check and it does'nt seems like it.

Anyone have an idea on what cause the redirection?

Comment: Possibly a silly question, but you do have `session_start()` included in your authentication code, too?

Comment: I was'nt sure so I double checked every page and yes it is present on every one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// server should keep session data for AT LEAST 1 hour
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);

// each client should remember their session id for EXACTLY 1 hour
session_set_cookie_params(3600);

session_start(); // ready to go!
```

Comment: This seems like a good answer but since the problem is solve and I don't want to go back and change something that works fine (in case I f*** something else), I can't verify that your answer is correct. But it is a better practice to change it your way instead of in php.ini directly. So I'll give you the answer but for future reference THIS ANSWER WAS NOT VERIFY! If someone happen to stumble across the same problem please check out this answer and comment back so we know it works. Thank you!